# adjustbox package effect all tables?

Tags: tables, longtable, scaling, adjustbox

I have a very long tables in rows and another in columns, i use  `adjustbox` package to resize these tables.

However, the other tables which are perfect fine get effect, some of them became in big font which different that in the thesis.
I need help, as I can not find why the table font size get bigger.

This is what I write for long table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{}
\label{}
\vspace{0.3cm}\centering\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

And this for the regular table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{}
\label{}
\vspace{0.3cm}\centering
\begin{tabular}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: One should only scale a table as a last resort, not the default.  That being said, you can check the size of a tabular using a savebox, so as to never increase the font size.

Comment: i did not understand,

Comment: See also https://www.ctan.org/topic/table

Comment: `{width=\textwidth}` scales smaller tables to the text width, which is probably not what you want. Use `{max width=\textwidth}` instead to only scale *down* if the width is larger than the text width. Also instead of `\centering` you might want to try to add the `center` key *after* the `max width` key.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate my comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] \caption{test caption} \vspace{0.3cm}
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{c}
a very small tabular
\end{tabular}}%
\ifdim\wd0>\textwidth
  \adjustbox{width=\textwidth}{\usebox0}
\else
  \centering
  \usebox0
\fi
\end{table}

\end{document}
```